# Point intersect-setting tolerances in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, point, intersect

I need to find out which polygon a series of points fall in.  Normally I would do this with an intersect so I can then export the data and process it externally.  As the point layer contains some coastal features some points fall outside of the polygon boundaries.

Is it possible to setup a tolerance such that if a value is going to return as null (or falls within a certain distance of a boundary) it returns the value of the nearest polygon?

Comment: Try Spatial Join with match option closest.

Comment: This looks like the more appropriate solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could buffer your polygons by the desired amount of tolerance and then intersect. Using joins you can then get the desired information.